# Convert String to array of integer in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Outline how a Java program could convert a string such as “1,2,3,4,5” into an array 
({1, 2, 3, 4,5})

Comment: Check this link: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090824115249AAXkde1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From zvzdhk:

```
String[] array = "1,2,3,4,5".split(",");
```

Then, parse your integers:

```
int[] ints = new int[array.length];
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    try {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);           
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //Not an integer 
    }
}
```

Comment: It work for me thank you for your response but how does the .split(",") work ?

Comment: Consult the Java API, it's a String method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String[] array = "1,2,3,4,5".split(",");
int[] result = new result[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    try {
         result[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StringTokenizer which will split string by comma and then put those values/tokens in array of integers.

```
public static int[] getIntegers(String numbers) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(numbers, ",");
    int[] intArr = new int[st.countTokens()];
    int i = 0;
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        intArr[i] = Integer.parseInt((String) st.nextElement());
        i++;
    }
    return intArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] str = "1,2,3,4,5".split(",");
int arrayInt[] = new int[str.length];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
    arrayInt[i]=Integer.valueOf(str[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Guava you can do this in one line:

```
int[] array = Ints.toArray(Lists.newArrayList(Ints.stringConverter().convertAll(Splitter.on(",").split("1,2,3,4,5"))));
```

or so (if you don't require an array):

```
Iterable<Integer> ints = Ints.stringConverter().convertAll(Splitter.on(",").split("1,2,3,4,5"));
```