# How to convert negative float number into binary vector in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point

How to convert float number like -2.25 to binary? I need creating a population for a genetic algorithm with domain from -20.5 to 20.5 . Each chromosomes should be represinted with 0s and 1s only

```
1 = 01
0 = 00
4 = 100
```

and so on

I know how to convert the "2" but not the 0.25 nor the number with negative sign

this is my method and I'm stuck there. I could not know how to enhance it to give me the correct result when converting float, negative int or negative float number

```
public class MinimizeRastriginFunction {

    public static String binary="";

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        //float x=(float) 2.5;
        int x =5 ;
        System.out.println("Before :" + x);
        decToBin(x);
        System.out.println("After :"  + binary);


    }

    private static Object decToBin(int dec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int num;

        if (dec <=1) {
            binary +=dec;
            return null;   // KICK OUT OF THE RECURSION
        }

        num= dec %2; 
        decToBin(dec >>1);
        binary += num;
        return null;    
    }
```

Comment: Start with [`Float.floatToRawIntBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits(float)). Then there are various ways of converting an `int` to a `byte[]`. Or you could `Integer.toBinaryString`.

Comment: Also, [mandatory link](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/).

Comment: I'd recommend to remove the misleading "genetic-algorithm" and "genetic-programming" tags.

Comment: Technically, `Float.parseFloat()` does exactly what you gave us as the question. It takes a string with a decimal representation of a fractional (floating point) number, e.g. "-2.25" and returns a `float`: a machine-oriented binary floating point representation. But I guess you want to see some readable string representation like "-10.01". Correct? And maybe you want to do it "yourself", not relying on some library.

Comment: Integer part is made of sum of positive powers of 2, and then decimal part is made of sum of negative powers of 2. So proceed by multiplying by 2 instead of dividing. 0.25*2=0.5 (retain 0), 0.5*2=1 (retain 1) then stop, so 0.25 is 0.01 in binary representation.

Comment: It is not quite clear how you would map values to bits. Could you give an example of how you would map a few values like -20.5, -19.7, +3.0, etc. etc. to bits?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
as per your comment, keep only 20 charachters then the solution would look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(convert("0.25"));
        System.out.println(convert("-0.25"));
        System.out.println(convert("2"));
        System.out.println(convert("-2"));
    }
    public static String convert(String input) {
        double number = Double.parseDouble(input);
        long longBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(number);
        String result = Long.toBinaryString(longBits);

        String upToNCharacters = result.substring(0, Math.min(result.length(), 20));
        return upToNCharacters;
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
11111111010000000000
10111111110100000000
10000000000000000000
11000000000000000000
```

---

why don't you try this approach. There is an inbuilt function that can help you

for example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(convert("0.25"));
        System.out.println(convert("-0.25"));

    }

    public static String convert(String input) {

        double number = Double.parseDouble(input);
        long longBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(number);
        String result = Long.toBinaryString(longBits);

        return result.replaceAll("0+$", "");;
    }

}
```

check also [here](https://ideone.com/X9duvS)

You can use it to convert everything you like dec, fload, negative dec/float(s)

```
System.out.println(convert("0.25"));
System.out.println(convert("-0.25"));
System.out.println(convert("2"));
System.out.println(convert("-2"));
```

Output would be:

```
11111111010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1011111111010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and to have some format in your output just do this (using regex to remove all trailing 0s):

```
return result.replaceAll("0+$", "");
```

and the output will be the one you desire

```
1111111101
101111111101
1
11
```

And finally if you need to return an array of Int (vector), or something else you can process them one by one by something like this mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271306/convert-string-to-array-of-integer-in-java). mmoore has provided a splendid answer for the conversion in a simple loop :)

Comment: how can I limit result in a fixed length all the time?

Comment: of course. What is your desired length? would you like to include trailing 0 at that or not?

Comment: I need the fixed length to be twenty

Comment: sure, check the beginning of the answer ;) I updated the code as per comments here

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't need infinite resolution for your numbers, e.g. `2.4999` need not get a different bit pattern than `2.5000`.

With a resolution if e.g. `0.01` you can do: `int bitsNumber = (int) ((value + 20.5) / 0.01);` and then convert the int to the binary string the way you already did it (or with `Integer.toBinaryString(bitsNumber)` ).